# extracting a string from a text field I get "Thread 1: signal SIGABRIT" if the character before the extract is a number

Tags: objective-c, regex, sigabrt

I am using Tesseract to scan a driving license, and I want to pre-populate some fields using the extracted information.

The format of the license goes:

1. WILLS
2. MATTHEW DAVID
   ... etc

My code (which I will add at the bottom) works if I am looking for "David" and start my search with "Matthew" ending with "\n"
However, if I start with "1. " trying to find "WILLS" then after the scan my app crashes.

For the record, "4a." works as well, so it's more likely that I can't "end" with a number, or "only" have a number, but either way, a number is the only consistent character I have to use as the key for my search, so what can I change in my code, to work for the above example.

It currently works with this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"1(.*?)\n" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];

[regexp enumerateMatchesInString:tesseractText.text
                         options:0
                           range:NSMakeRange(0, tesseractText.text.length)
                      usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
    {
        NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
        tesseractText.text = [tesseractText.text substringWithRange:group1]; // changes textField to value of specific text
    }
];
```

In my example, I simple change the current textfield to the text I am searching for, a testing mechanism before implementing the full code, but rest assured, it didn't create any bugs with the previous searches (starting and ending with letters, starting with letters and ending with \n, or starting with 4a. and ending with \n, but it refused to work with "1. " "1" "2 " or "2."

```
NSRegularExpression *regexp = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"MATTHEW (.*?)\n"
```

works when searching for David

Any suggestions on how I can get this to work, with just the numbers at the start of each line to go by?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The SIGABRT is because you are *assuming* there will be a `rangeAtIndex:1`. You must not assume that. All Objective-C indexes start at 0. The first and only guaranteed range is `rangeAtIndex:0`. If you want to know whether there are any further ranges, you need to ask for the `numberOfRanges`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand why that would only make a difference now. By changing "rangeAtIndex" to 0, it only means that it includes the text I am using to search so:
@"1.(.*?)\n" = "1.Wills"
instead of what I want which is:
@"1.(.*?)\n" = "Wills"

Also, it doesn't stop the error, the crash still occurs even if I change "rangeAtIndex" to 0. So unless you meant something else, it unfortunately does not solve the problem AND gets an undesired output.

Comment: The question was that you are crashing. I am telling you how not to crash. Crashing is bad. Don't crash. Rewrite your code so that you don't crash. After that you can worry about the regular expression pattern.

Comment: I sent a reply by accident, and did so a couple times trying to fix it, so maybe you didn't get my previous response, but I was saying that what I understand from what you suggested, did not stop the crash, and it also changed the output, have I misunderstood your recommended change?

Comment: How do I know what you have understood? All I know is what the code says. You have badly written code that runs the risk of crashing. You need to write your code so that it doesn't crash even if the search fails.

Comment: Put simply, I am referring to the line: NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:1]; and that the problem is that I am assuming it starts at 1, so changing it to: NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:0]; circumvents that assumption. I am asking you if that is what you meant, that's how you can know what I have understood, if what I have written is not what you meant, then I need to look elsewhere.

Comment: Of course that is not what I meant. You want group 1 - but you can only get group 1 _if group 1 exists_. As I said in my answer, you must ask for the `numberOfRanges` first and _find out_ whether group 1 exists. If it doesn't, then don't ask for it or you will crash.

Comment: I apologise if I am upsetting you, but this is new territory for me and nothing is obvious. Looking back at your first answer, I only see a reference to "rangeAtIndex" and not what or where I need to ask for numberOfRanges, so I asked what I thought was obvious first to eliminate it as a possibility. Now I am thinking that "int desiredRange = 1" "if (match.numberOfRanges >= desiredRange){NSRange group1 = [match rangeAtIndex:desiredRange]; ... etc etc is a change along these lines what you meant?

Comment: You are just making me repeat myself. Read my answer! I've already explained this. Indexes start at 0. So if there is to be a group 1, there must be at least _two_ ranges. Just read the docs! "Passing rangeAtIndex: the value 0 always returns the value of the the range property. Additional ranges, if any, will have indexes from 1 to numberOfRanges-1."

Answer (score 0):

I never did fully understand what was causing the problem (despite Matt explaining that I needed to ask something for numberOfRanges) but I did figure out why my code was rejecting "numbers" but not "letters"

The actually problem was not the numbers at all but the "." that came after them. In Regex the "." after a character is a command, and when implemented with the numbers, was triggering an event that lead to the SIGABRIT, which Matt explained (if I am correct in saying so), was because my code lacked a failsafe for such an event. Sorry I can't explain it any better, but while I understand now what was stopping my code from working, I am still not clear on the exact order of events that lead to that specific error.

Anyway, instead of searching for - ( @"1. (.*?)\n" )

I typed in - ( @"1[.] (.*?)\n" )

// ( ) are for clarity, since the code include " already

The [.] takes the "." as a literal character instead of a command, so it is treated the same way as my earlier efforts @"MATTHEW (.*?)\n" for example, which accurately returned David.

By changing 1. to 1[.] I am now able to extract the full name "Matthew David" instead of random other text or crashing the program altogether

This is a rare combination of problems/requirements, but hopefully if anyone ever does encounter this problem again, this will help them find a speedy solution